# Does Visual Studio Freeze all threads when it hits a breakpoint?

Tags: visual-c++, breakpoints, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019

I have a bug that's popping up, which is that when I'm running a separate (luckily open source) library, when I run it normally, it encounters an error and crashes.

However, when it place a breakpoint to trace through and figure out why it's crashing.. it works.

I suspect that what's happening is that the thread that contains the breakpoint is waiting on the other thread to complete a task, without which is crashes. Normally, the other thread isn't ready yet. However, when I have a breakpoint, it has time to complete before I click 'Step Over' I know that I can force other threads to freeze, after the breakpoint is hit but I really want the freeze to be at the exact instant that I hit the breakpoint.

Comment: The debugger stops all threads in the process when the debugger encounters a breakpoint. This can be seen by opening the Debug|Windows|Threads dialog, switching thread contexts and seeing the callstack of each frozen thread.

Comment: Threading race bugs critically depend on timing.  Make the code a wee bit faster or slower and the bug doesn't byte.  Could be as simple as debugging the non-optimized build of the library.  You must assume, unless explicitly advertised, that a library is never thread-safe and that you therefore must serialize calls into the library yourself.